# many to many spring jpa not returning all data in JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have created a many to many relationship. It is returning the data correctly. However, I noticed that if the data exist in canUse section of the json and has been called before by another Player, it does not print the data again only the new values are printed.

JOSN

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "firstname": "asdfghjkl ",
        "surname": "asda",
        "canUse": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "techniqueName": "JAVA"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "techniqueName": "PHP"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "techniqueName": "PYTHON"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 49,
        "firstname": "asc",
        "surname": "as",
        "canUse": []
    },
    {
        "id": 90,
        "firstname": "LOL",
        "surname": "LOL",
        "canUse": []
    }*,
    {
        "id": 91,
        "firstname": "Kareem",
        "surname": "LOL",
        "canUse": [
            1,
            2,
            {
                "id": 3,
                "techniqueName": "HASKELL"
            }
        ]
    },*
    {
        "id": 92,
        "firstname": "Omar",
        "surname": "LOL",
        "canUse": []
    }
]
```

Player entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Players {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="player_id")
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String surname;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "able_to_use",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "player_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "technique_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private List<Technique> canUse;
    //Getters and Setters
```

Technique entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "technique")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Technique {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "technique_name")
    private String techniqueName;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "canUse", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Players> ableToUse;
      //Getters and Setters
```

Thank you in advance, the problem is occurring for player with ID 91. this player should also print PHP and PYTHON but only the ID is printed.

Comment: canUse will fail to deserialize with normal mapper

Comment: @silentsudo Can you please clarify? Sorry, i am a total noob at this.